# Bash: Trouble when using cat for a lot of files

Tags: bash, limit, command-line-arguments, cat

For each set of parameters I try to merge 400 data files with 13 lines each to a large one like this:

```
folders=(*/)
for folder in ${folders[@]}; do
    #FIND SIGMA
    sig0=${folder#*sig}
    sig=${sig0%amax*}
    #MERGE
    cat sig${sig}amax0.6_incr0.1/tau*.dat > merged_sigma${sig}amax0.6_incr0.1.dat
done
```

It's easy math that a merged file should have 5200 lines, but it doesn't.
Instead, each merged file has a different number of lines, varying between about 3100 and 5000.

I've checked that all the `tau*.dat` files exist, are not empty and have exactly 13 lines.
There is no problem with missing line breaks at the ends of the small files. In the merged file all lines have the same length. Just some - and it seems to me in a random manner - are missing.

I've read somewhere that the total number of characters in all the file names together mustn't exceed 32767 characters. However, even when taking into account that the file names are not `tau*.dat` but `sig0.10amax0.1_incr0.1/tau27.0_sigma0.10__-0.6-0.6_0-0_0.1.dat` I only have no more than 25000 characters for each cat command.

Comment: Assuming no filenames have embedded spaces, count the number of files that the globbing pattern expands to as follows: `echo sig${sig}amax0.1_incr0.1/tau*.dat | wc -w`

Comment: getconf ARG_MAX will show the maximum allowed number of characters, not filenames.  On unix-like installations like cygwin this is 32K bytes, not file names.  Note also that _POSIX_ARG_MAX (the standard minimum) is 4096 bytes.

Comment: echo sig${sig}amax0.1_incr0.1/tau*.dat | wc -w gives 1
echo sig${sig}amax0.1_incr0.1/tau*.dat | wc -c gives 25101
ARG_MAX is about 2 million. So concerning the length of the command I should be fine.

Comment: If `echo sig${sig}amax0.1_incr0.1/tau*.dat | wc -w` returns `1`, the implication is that the pattern matches either just 1 file or none at all - which contradicts your `wc -c` statement. If @sputnick's approach didn't help, the problem must lie elsewhere: (a) Does the globbing pattern really match all the files you THINK it does? (b) Do all files really contain exactly 13 lines? P.S.: As a commenter I don't automatically get notified of further comments. To notify a specific commenter of a response, include `@<username>`. Also, enclosing bits of code in backticks makes them more readable.

Comment: @jimmcnamara Excellent pointer; two things to add: (a) in practice, the limit is lower - http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ recommends the following formula: `$(( $(getconf ARG_MAX) - $(env|wc -c) - $(env|wc -l) * 4 - 2048 ))`; (b) the limit is in *bytes*, not characters, so with, say, UTF8-encoded text, the limit in *characters* may be lower.

Comment: One more thought: if the length of the `cat` command line were the problem, you'd see `bash: /bin/cat: Argument list too long` output on stderr, and the exit code would be 126.

Comment: @user3077484: Did you ever figure out what the problem was? Another thing I just noticed, though probably unrelated, is that `${folders[@]}` should be `"${folders[@]}"` (double-quoted) to ensure that folder names with embedded spaces and other shell metacharacters are handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do :

```
folders=(*/)
for folder in ${folders[@]}; do
    #FIND SIGMA
    sig0=${folder#*sig}
    sig=${sig0%amax*}
    #MERGE
    for file in sig${sig}amax0.1_incr0.1/tau*.dat; do
        cat "$file" >> "merged_sigma${sig}amax0.6_incr0.1.dat"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Note: This answer explains how to avoid the problem of the command line getting too long when using globbing; however, the command-line length limit appears *not* to be the source of the OP's problem.</sup>

**To reliably process globs that expand to argument lists of arbitrary size** - without worrying about running into the command-line length limit - you can use the following approach:

```
printf '%s\0' *  | xargs -0 ...
```

This is based on the following **assumptions**:

- `printf` is (also) a **shell builtin** and therefore *not* subject to the command-line length limit (as reported by `getconf ARG_MAX` - the size of the environment; see http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) - true at least for `bash` (run `type printf` to verify that `printf` is a builtin in your shell).
- `xargs` supports the `-0` option to accept null char.-separated input; note that a core feature of `xargs` is to respect the command-line length limit and partition the argument list into *multiple invocations* of the specified command, if necessary.

  - *Caveat*: `-0` is a nonstandard (not POSIX-compliant) option, but it's supported on both Linux and BSD-like platforms such as OSX.
- (Only if you know that your filenames contain no spaces (and no newlines) and do not start with `-` can you use the simplified form `echo * | xargs ...`, similarly assuming that `echo` is a shell builtin.)

If we apply this approach to the OP's code, we get:

```
printf '%s\0' sig${sig}amax0.6_incr0.1/tau*.dat | 
  xargs -0 cat > merged_sigma${sig}amax0.6_incr0.1.dat
```